# For looping an array?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Just starting to grasp the ropes on c-programming, but I'm trying to create a function that can compute numbers from a given base to a decimal format.
(base_to_int)

For example,
digits1[] = {2, 3, 4, 5} in base 10 = 5432
and 
digits2[] = {5, 6, 7} in base 8 = 501

it looks like when I try to run a for loop through, it doesn't seem to be computing it, and I keep getting the last digit in the array (for digits1, the answer for the output I keep getting is "5")...

why can't I run a for loop through the array?

**CODE:**

ndigits = number of digits in the array, digits = array, base = the base the array number is in.

```
int base_to_int(int ndigits, int* digits, int base)
{
  for (int n = 0 ; n <= ndigits - 1 ; n++)
    {
      int a = digits[n];
      return  a * pow(base,n);
      }
}
```

for this code, I keep getting the output "2" when I try to compile it.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the first result of the calculations, remember, `return` ends the execution of the function and simply returns the value, so you're having only one iteration and not looping and summing all values, your code is equivalent to:

```
return  digits[0] * pow(base,0);
```

Change

```
return a * pow(base, n);
```

to

```
sum += a * pow(base, n)
```

You should return `sum` *outside* the loop, when you finish the calculations (don't forget to initialize `sum` to 0 outside the loop).

Comment: Thank you! Rookie mistake on my part

Comment: Happens :) The most important thing is to learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

As Maroun Maroun said,when you write the return statement,the function returns and never computes the later part.